# Getting the following error for Yubico API call

Tags: yubico, yubikey

I am trying to create a new order in yubico portal using API call via service now.

Getting the following error:
Access denied to create new email

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the authors of Yubico's ServiceNow guide. In order to help troubleshhot we will need additional payload information.

Could you please open a request at this link so that we can begin to look into your error; [YubiEnterprise Services - Contact Support](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubienterprise/contact-support/)

This will ensure that we're not exposing any sensitive payload information on this public channel.

You could also consult the documentation to see if your error message has a quick solution:

- [YubiEnterprise documentation](https://console.yubico.com/help/api-req.html#)
- [API specification](https://console.yubico.com/apidocs/#operation/CreateShipmentExact)

Off the top of my head I would suggest to see if:

- You have generated a valid API token from your console
- You are making a request using the url "https://api.console.stage.yubico.com/v1"

Comment: Can we setup a call with someone to address this issue?

Comment: Yes, support can be provided by contacting YubiEnterprise support here - https://www.yubico.com/products/yubienterprise/contact-support/